# Refactor create_function() to an anonymous function using RectorPHP

Tags: php, anonymous-function, create-function, rector

For php 7.2 compatibility, I need to refactor the following create_function() to an anonymous function:

```
function bbpp_thankmelater_shortcode_h($atts, $content = NULL) {
    extract(Bbpp_ThankMeLater_Shortcoder::atts(array(
        "email_type" => NULL,
        "comment" => NULL,
        "level" => 1
    ), $atts));
    
    if ($email_type == "text") {
        return str_repeat("*", $level) . " " . $content;
    }
    
    return "<h{$level}>" . $content . "</h{$level}>";
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    Bbpp_ThankMeLater_Shortcoder::add("h{$i}", create_function("\$atts,\$content", "\$atts[\"level\"]={$i};return bbpp_thankmelater_shortcode_h(\$atts, \$content);"));
}
```

When using [Rector](https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2018/12/17/function-create-function-is-deprecated-in-php-72-how-to-migrate/) to do it automatically I get this error:

```
 [ERROR] Could not process "shortcodes/h.php" file, due to:                                        
         "Syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR, expecting ']':1".
```

Any Idea? Thx in advance for your help